# Android extend up button

Tags: android, up-button

I want to extend the up button on the actionbar to include the activity name. For example, instead of only being able to click the arrow to go back, I could also click the words next to it. I know some apps allow this but I haven't seen any instructions on how to do it.

Here is an example of what it currently allows:

[image]

Here is an example of what I want it to do:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a custom layout in your toolbar. Then when the user clicks on the view containing the title text and the up button, you handle the logic yourself.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/primary"
    app:contentInsetStart="72dp"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

<!--Contains your up button and title text-->    
<SomeCustomLayout
        android:id="@+id/customLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Then get the view in your code with

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
SomeCustomLayout customLayout = toolbar.findViewById(R.id.customLayout);
customLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // You'll probably want to fire off 
        // an intent here to go back to the parent activity
    }
```

});